# Editar varias filas con un UPDATE dentro de trigger

Tags: mysql

Actualmente tengo el siguiente trigger

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `actualiza_precio` AFTER UPDATE ON `producto`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 UPDATE precioventa SET precio = NEW.precio WHERE id = 
 NEW.id;
 END
```

Resulta que cree un campo nuevo llamado precio2, entonces cuando el usuario modifique en la tabla de productiso el precio2 quiero que se modifique en la venta

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualiza_precio` AFTER UPDATE ON `producto`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 UPDATE precioventa SET precio2 = NEW.precio2 WHERE id = 
 NEW.id;
 END
```

Pero recibo el error que no puedo realizar multiples sentencias con la misma accion? no necesariamente debe ejecutarse simultaneamente solo cuando cuando alguno de los campos: precio, precio2 se hayan modificado, gracias por la ayuda que pueda brindarme

Comment: Son precios distintos que va a manejar la venta según el cliente entonces cada precio, y precio2 van a ser distintos, pero necesito actualizar la ventas cuando se modifique cualquiera de los dos campos, según lei puedo hacerlos juntos pero no se mucho de Mysql entonces no se como integrar los dos set

Comment: Edite la pregunta porque veo que no la formulé bien, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Te acabo de contestar pero me acaba de entrar una duda. ¿El id del producto es el mismo id de la venta?

Comment: corrió perfecto gracias por tu valiosa ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si cambia algo en la tabla `producto`, se busca que se actualice la tabla `precioventa` que corresponda con la condición.

Puedes mezclar ambas sentencias en el `UPDATE`; como si fuese otro valor más que modificar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza_precio
    AFTER UPDATE ON producto
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    UPDATE precioventa
      SET precio2 = NEW.precio2,
          precio = NEW.precio
      WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END;
```

Comment: Excelente gracias por tu gran ayuda tenia toda la mañana tratando de unificar las dos actualizaciones